# No module named 'db_dtypes'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Running a small python code to create a pandas dataframe from Bigquery table results . When i run the code I see the below results. The db_dtypes is already installed , not sure what other dependencies i need to add. Any help is appreciated.

Here is the code

```
import pandas

from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.oauth2 import service_account

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    '/Users/kar/Downloads/data-4045ff698b4f.json')

project_id = 'data-platform'
client = bigquery.Client(credentials=credentials, project=project_id)



sql = """SELECT * FROM `data-platform.airbnb.raw_hosts` LIMIT 1"""
query_job = client.query(sql)
df = query_job.to_dataframe()
```

Error

```
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ka/PycharmProjects/pythonProject4/main.py", line 17, in <module>
    df = query_job.to_dataframe()
  File "/Users/ka/PycharmProjects/pythonProject4/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/job/query.py", line 1689, in to_dataframe
    geography_as_object=geography_as_object,
  File "/Users/ka/PycharmProjects/pythonProject4/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/table.py", line 1965, in to_dataframe
    _pandas_helpers.verify_pandas_imports()
  File "/Users/ka/PycharmProjects/pythonProject4/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/_pandas_helpers.py", line 991, in verify_pandas_imports
    raise ValueError(_NO_DB_TYPES_ERROR) from db_dtypes_import_exception
ValueError: Please install the 'db-dtypes' package to use this function.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: You included only some of your code. Please include sufficient code to provide a minimal repro of the issue. You say that `db_dtypes` is installed (how?). Did you also include `import db_dtypes` in your code?

Comment: Please don't include images when you can copy-paste text. Images aren't searchable, copy-paste-able and may have a different lifetime than the question.

Comment: Have you tried running `pip install db-dtypes` https://pypi.org/project/db-dtypes/ Also as @DazWilkin comment its a good idea to include sufficient code and include texts for logs etc to help the community to identify and replicate your inquiry.

Comment: Yes i have already installed the db-dtpyes.

Comment: Added the entire code to the original post

Comment: What is the version of your `db-types` and `google-cloud-bigquery`?

Comment: Did you manage to fix it? I'm having the same issue ATM

Comment: It worked for me after doing two things: 1. run `pip install db-dtypes` and 2. [restart](https://support.labs.cognitiveclass.ai/knowledgebase/articles/857388-how-to-restart-the-jupyter-kernel) the kernel. Then everything worked.

Answer (score 2):

Importing BigQuery tables into pandas appears to be such a pain, that there is a pandas method (and associated library) for it (see [pandas.read_gcp](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_gbq.html)).

I recommend using this module instead of the native *bigquery* module.

```
import pandas_gbq
... # your code for getting credentials and query-string
df = pandas_gbq.read_gbq(sql, project_id=project_id, credentials=credentials, progress_bar_type=None)
```

For me using this library, I can convert the response into a data frame but when converting the data frame into *pickle* format and then reimporting it to an environment without *pandas_gbq* it produces the same error...

I assume that some meta-data can not be displayed properly by the vanilla pandas module.

**Edit**: By looking at the comments one can find out that the error can be easily mended by simply doing `pip install db-dtypes` as @DazWilkin and @Nestor Ceniza Jr suggest (and restarting the kernel if you're using jupyter notebooks as @dss does)

Answer (score 1):

After running `pip install db-dtypes` it worked for me.